# What game are Mio and Yuko playing on the train?

Tags: nichijou

In Nichijou Episode 0 (OVA), Mio and Yuko are playing a game on the train:

[image: Come at me Mio!]

They push and feint at each other but the game doesn't finish as they are distracted by Mai sleeping in the baggage area.

[image: Urgghhh!]
[image: Phwaa!]

How does this game work? What's the objective?

Comment: It kinda looks like a low key version of Sumo Wrestling

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The objective is to make your opponent move their feet or otherwise lose their footing.  There are a wide variety of rulesets and variations.  This one seems to be pretty basic:

- Each player stands feet apart with toes pointing at each other.
- Hands are placed palm to palm, palms of your opponent are the only part of them you can touch.
- Push or pull your hands to throw your opponent off balance.
- Whoever shifts their feet first loses.

Some varieties include:

- Clasp right hands and try and shift your opponent's footing.
- Push anywhere to shift your opponents footing.